# Capybara: to find element which got a click

Tags: selenium, capybara

I am using Cucumber with Selenium webdriver.

When there is logout method in

```
After do |scenario|
```

and the logout button does not get a click (in my example there exists another big div that blocks everything), in report I get an error that tells me which element would actually get a click:

```
unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (979, 15). Other element would receive the click: <div class="locking-layer show"></div>
```

Is it possible to implement such a check that would tell which element got a click from user? That can be helpful in "clickability" checks when an element does not change its state (class name, attributes etc.) after a click.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved same functionality with different approach, I had define a step in my feature file like

```
And I logout
```

then in step definition we accomplish this by:

```
page.execute_script("jQuery('#profile_dropdown').show();") # I have dropdown in which there is a link 'Logout'
click_link('Logout')
```

I think you will get an idea.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I have asked. The question is how to determine which element actually received a click? Maybe with the help of jQuery, although I tried to find a way within Capybara methods. It does not matter what`s this - logout or just a click, whatever.

Comment: Still want to figure out whether it is possible to do with Capybara. For example, the first part is pretty clear - find(element).click, but how to catch which element receives a click?

Comment: It would be difficult to check which element clicked in testing with capybara,  It would be great if you give me more code so we can achieve this task with different approach.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I do now instead of just catching the clicked element is to simulate mouse click on the coordinates of the desired element and to check that page address has not changed. 
**Obviously, it works only for such cases as logout when it is easy to determine the changes, and it does not solve the issue in general.**

For now (although still hope to find and use Capybara methods in order to catch a clicked element) I get the desired selector, determine its coordinates and click them.

```
def get_position(selector)   
    page.execute_script <<-EOS
      var elem1 = document.querySelector('#{selector}');
      var rect1 = elem1.getBoundingClientRect();
      return [rect1.left, rect1.top];   
    EOS 
end

def click_position(x, y)   
    page.execute_script <<-EOS
      $(document.elementFromPoint(#{x}, #{y})).click();
    EOS 
end

Then /^within "here is section of web-page" I click on the coordinates of "here is the name of the element"$/ do |section, click_target|
  section.to_s
  click_target.to_s
  section = human2selector(section)

  # get selector
  click_target = "#{section} #{click_target}"

  # get position of element
  click_target_coordinates = get_position(click_target)

  # click coordinates (each coordinate + 1) of element
  click_position((click_target_coordinates[0] + 1).to_i, (click_target_coordinates[1] + 1).to_i)
end
```